# Per vertex diffuse lighting not propogating across entire model

Tags: opengl, java, glsl

I'm not sure how to describe this problem so I've added a picture.  When I add per vertex diffuse lighting to my model (just a field of cubes for simplicity) the lighting effect applies to each surface individually instead of having the lighting gradually intensify or drop off across the entire plane.[image]

As you can see, each plane has it's own version of the shading effect.  I was expecting the collection of planes to be treated as a single surface with a uniform shading effect spread across it.  What would cause this?  Is it a common lighting mistake?  I have hardcoded the vertex normals for now as:

```
float[] normals = {0,0,1, //front
      -1,0,0,//left
      0,0,-1,//back
      1,0,0,//right
      0,1,0,//top
      0,-1,0//bottom
};

int[] idxBuffer = {0,1,2,2,3,0, //front
      4,0,3,3,4,5, //left
      4,6,7,7,5,4, //back
      1,6,7,7,2,1, //right
      3,2,7,7,5,3, //top
      0,1,6,6,4,0 //bottom
      };

float[] vertBuffer = {-1,-1,1,//0
      1,-1, 1,//1
      1,1,1,//2
      -1,1,1,//3
      -1,-1,-1,//4
      -1,1,-1,//5
      1,-1,-1,//6
      1,1,-1//7
};

//after initializing/linking shader...
  /****
   * Diffuse
   */
  //get indexes from shader variables...
  iModelView = shader.getUniform("ModelviewMatrix");
  iNorm = shader.getUniform("NormalMatrix");
  iMVP = shader.getUniform("MVP");
  iLightPos = shader.getUniform("LightPosition");
  iKd = shader.getUniform("Kd");
  iLd = shader.getUniform("Ld");

  //set the constant values in shader.
  float[] kd = {0.8f, 0.45f, 0.3f};
  shader.setUniform(iKd, kd, Shade.MatDataType.VEC3);
  float[] ld = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
  shader.setUniform(iLd, ld, Shade.MatDataType.VEC3);   

  /**
   * Prepare the normals.
   *This is my original attempt at creating per vertex normals. 
   */
  for(int i = 0; i < idxBuffer.length; i+=3)
  {
     Vector3 v0 = new Vector3( vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i]*3)],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i]*3)+1],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i]*3)+2]);
     Vector3 v1 = new Vector3( vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+1]*3)],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+1]*3)+1],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+1]*3)+2]);
     Vector3 v2 = new Vector3( vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+2]*3)],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+2]*3)+1],vertBuffer[(idxBuffer[i+2]*3)+2]);

     //Vector3 normal = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(v2 - v0, v1 - v0));
     Vector3 normal = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Sub(v2,v0) , Vector3.Sub(v1,v0)));

     normals[i+0] += normal.X;
     normals[i+1] += normal.Y;
     normals[i+2] += normal.Z;

  }
  for(int i = 0; i < idxBuffer.length; i+=3)
  {
      Vector3 tmp = new Vector3(normals[i+0],normals[i+1],normals[i+2]);
      Vector3 norm = Vector3.Normalize(tmp);
      normals[i+0] = norm.X;
      normals[i+1] = norm.Y;
      normals[i+2] = norm.Z;
  }

  vboHandles = new int[3];
  gl.glGenBuffers(3, vboHandles, 0);


  //populate the position buffer
  FloatBuffer fbData = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vertBuffer);
  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[VERTICES_IDX]); //the vertex data
  gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbData.capacity() * 4, 
          fbData, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  fbData.clear(); 

   //populate the normals buffer
  FloatBuffer fbnorm = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(normals);
  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[NORMALS_IDX]); //the normals data
  gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbnorm.capacity() * 4, 
          fbnorm, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  fbnorm.clear();   

//index buffer IBO Vertex
  IntBuffer dtaIndc = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(idxBuffer);
  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[IBO_IDX]); //bind the indices to the vertex data
  gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dtaIndc.capacity() * (Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE), 
          dtaIndc, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  dtaIndc.clear();

  //set vertex array index
  IntBuffer intBuffer = BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(1);
  gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, intBuffer);
  iVao = intBuffer.get(0);
  gl.glBindVertexArray(iVao);

  gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTICES_IDX);
  gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(NORMALS_IDX);

  //normals
  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[NORMALS_IDX]);
  gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL4.GL_FLOAT, true, 0, 0);  

  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[VERTICES_IDX]); //the vertex data
  // Associate Vertex attribute 1 with the last bound VBO
  gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL2ES2.GL_FLOAT, false,0,0);

  //bind IBO
  gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[2]);
```

**The Vertex shader**

```
layout (location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout (location=1) in vec3 vertexNormal;

out vec3 LightIntensity;

//uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelviewMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

uniform vec4 LightPosition;  //light position in eye coords.
uniform vec3 Kd;  //diffuse light reflectivity     
uniform vec3 Ld;  //light source intensity

void main(void) {

    //convert normal and position to eye coords
    vec3 tnorm = normalize( NormalMatrix * vertexNormal );
    vec4 eyeCoords = ModelviewMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    vec3 s = normalize( vec3(LightPosition - eyeCoords) );


    //the diffuse shading equation
    LightIntensity = Ld * Kd * max( dot( s, tnorm ), 0.0);

    //convert position to clip coordinates and pass along
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);

}
```

**The Display routine**

```
GL4 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL4();
gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL4.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


float x = 0;
float z = 0;

Quaternion q = new Quaternion();

FloatUtil.makeIdentity(view2);
FloatUtil.makeIdentity(vw2);


//10 is the distance from centre to ground that eye is looking.
float eyeY = (float) (10 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotAngleY)));
float eyeZ = (float) (10 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotAngleY)));

float[] eye = {0, 5 + eyeY, -30 + eyeZ};
float[] center = {0,0,0};
float[] up = {0,1,0};
float[] mat4Tmp = new float[16];
FloatUtil.makeLookAt(vw3, 0, eye, 0, center, 0, up, 0, mat4Tmp);

float[] lp = {5.0f,5.0f,2.0f,1.0f};

shader.setUniform(iLightPos, multiply4(lp, vw3), Shade.MatDataType.VEC4);

int yyy = 0;
//draw field    
for ( x = -60  ;x < 60 ; x+=2){
    for ( z = -60  ; z < 60 ; z+=2){

        view2 = vw3;

        //rotate the scene
        q = q.setIdentity();
        q = q.rotateByAngleNormalAxis( (float) Math.toRadians(rotAngle), 0, 1, 0);
        q = q.normalize();

        q.toMatrix(vw2, 0);

        //mult rotation and perspective
        view2 = multiply( view2, vw2);

        //apply the updated translation co-ords to vertices
        if ((x % 10) == 0){yyy = 1;}else{yyy=0;}
        view2 = translate(view2, (float)-transX-x, transY+yyy, -(transZ-z));

        shader.setUniform(iModelView, view2, Shade.MatDataType.MAT4);

        float[] norm = {view2[0],view2[1],view2[2],
                view2[4],view2[5],view2[6],
                view2[8],view2[9],view2[10]
        };

        shader.setUniform(iNorm, norm, Shade.MatDataType.MAT3);
        shader.setUniform(iMVP, multiply(projection,  view2), Shade.MatDataType.MAT4);

      //link view matrix to 'mat4 modelView' on vertex shader. 

         //draw 12 triangles (36 vertices).
        gl.glBindVertexArray(iVao);
        //gl.glDrawArrays(GL4.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        gl.glDrawElements(
                 GL4.GL_TRIANGLES,      // mode
                 idxBuffer.length,    // count
                 GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,   // type
                 0           // element array buffer offset
             );

    }
}
```

Any help, hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are you passing your normals to the vertex shader? It looks like those are the normals for each of the six faces of a cube, but the vertex shader operates on vertices, not faces. Unless you're doing something unusual, you need to specify a normal for each vertex.

In addition, if you want a cube to look right, you will need 24 vertices rather than 8, so that the vertex normals for each of the four vertices around one face point in the same direction. If you just have 8 vertices (which probably seems most natural, for a cube), each vertex will be shared by three faces. This is good for most situations, where you want smooth lighting across faces, but probably not what you're looking for when trying to light a cube.

Comment: I did initially create a normal per vertex but I was getting the same result.  I've added the code I was using to generate the normals in my post as well as the complete shader code.  The normals are being passed to the shader via the Location index - see   gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandles[NORMALS_IDX]);
  gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL4.GL_FLOAT, true, 0, 0);    Also, I don't really understand how I can have 24 vertices for a square?  If the upper/left/front is at 1,1,1 what other vertices apply?

Comment: @eric_user1775643 you need three vertices at the point (1,1,1) - one with each of the normals (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1)

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone.  I think I understand enough enough to experiment with this.  I'll start with a single plane, calculate the normal for each vertex (6 in total - 2 triangles) and go from there.

Comment: Just another note for anyone else who might be reading this.  You have to take into consideration the 'winding' of the triangles to determine which way the normals will be facing.  For example a counterclockwise winding would indicate an 'outward' facing normal and clockwise would be inward facing.  Of course you can alter the direction by inverting the normal.  I got this from the OpenGL docs and thought it should be noted as an important element for new programmers to be aware of.  BTW - read the doc yourself, don't take my 'newbie' explanation at face value!